# Saving sessions on log out

Tags: php, session, authentication, session-storage

I am a beginner in PHP,trying to create a simple ecommerce site. I have a login/registration form and user is able to add items or choose options that will only affect his/her account. On logging out,im using session_destroy() hence everything returns back to default. I also tried using arrays so that I can save and add items in the session array:

```
 $_SESSION['user_info'] = array();
 array_push($_SESSION['user_info'],        $item1);
```

I'm stuck on how to log out the user and retain their info,in the logout.php file I'm unsetting the session like this:

```
 session_start();
 unset($_SESSION['user_info']);
 session_destroy();
```

But on logging back again,nothing is saved.I would gladly appreciate any help.

Comment: Thats not the Purpose, Sessions are made for. You need to save the "Basket" somewhere else, like in a Database.

Comment: `beginner in PHP...registration form` are you encrypting the user data using an community standard library like Sodium? Are you enforcing HTTPS on all requests? Are passwords one way hashed before being stored? eCommerse platforms are complicated, and quickly. Recommend trying something a little smaller as a beginning project. As for the cart items, I'd say save that to a database table. user<->user_items<->items type relation.

Comment: If you need to keep with cart info you can't destroy the session. If session is destroyed all informations is lost. Only unset the user_info session index.

Comment: you need a database my friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is saved because `session_destroy()` deletes the session data. Sessions are only intended to store data while the customer is active or logged in. Either use `file_put_contents` to save data with `file_get_contents` to retrieve the data, or create a database, such as `MySQL`.

[file_get_contents](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_file_get_contents.asp)

[MySQL](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/)

[Save Session To Database](http://culttt.com/2013/02/04/how-to-save-php-sessions-to-a-database/)